# Query about average velocity of gas molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas

When we can say that gas molecule average velocity is 0 and in which case it is not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. In the kinetic theory, the velocity of the molecules is proportional to the square root of the temperature - so it would never be zero.

Comment: If you talk about velocity as a vector, velocity in all directions is about equal so the ad up to zero,

Answer (score 0):

Well if you consider gas molecules in an isolated container then every particle is moving randomly and thus seeing everything as a part of a bigger system which appears at rest we conclude that the net velocity is zero.

In case where you have a moving piston which is compressing the gas let say with a constant velocity v. then all the gas particles acquire a additional velocity (parallel to the constant velocity) along with its original velocity and now when you take the net again the old velocity vector will add upto zero but there will be some net velocity this time due to the moving piston.